# How should I typeset the complex conjugate of a subscripted variable?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have a variable `$z_{2n+1}$` and I want to write the complex conjugate of it.  I am not sure which of the following should be preferred:

- `\bar{z}_{2n+1}`: The bar is not so large and may be hard to notice.
- `\overline{z_{2n+1}}`: The bar seems to extend too far to the left.
- `\overline{z}_{2n+1}`: Worst of both worlds?

I know I could tweak the length of the bar, but I'm not really sure what output I should be aiming for.  Is there a standard way to typeset this, or other best practices to consider?

I am using AMS-LaTeX.

Comment: There is no rule to write it. I've seen both on many books. I'd write the 3rd option but to be precise what you want is to apply the conjugation function at the $2n+1$-th element of the sequence (not take the $2n+1$-th element of a sequence of conjugates).

Comment: \stackrel{\rule{1em}{1pt}}{z} is overkill, but adjustable.